# UnknownFormatConversionException with String.format in Java

Tags: java

Why am I getting the error java.util.UnknownConversionException: Conversion = 'D' for the method below. I create an intial string, then return that from a method to do a String.format.  It happens at the String.format.

```
String url = StringUtils.join(new String[] { BASE_URL,
                "/location/inst/", slug,
                "/coursesections/number%s.json?apiKey=", apiKey,
                "&token=", GetAuthTokenEncoded(authToken) })


String url2 = String.format(url, ("/" + callNumber));
```

**Output of StringUtils**

```
http://test.com/location/inst/testy/coursesections/number%s;.json?apiKey=dfsdfsdfsadfsdf&token=2.0%7Cidm%7Cidm%7Ctest%3Dbesrlin_50d4s9dd25dsee56f3a1e95fb4f%26berlin%3D50d49dd2e2f28cf450b0caa9f449%26campus%3Dberlin%3A50d49dd25ee56f3a1e95fb4f%7C2013-03-12T16%3A25%3A23%2B00%3A00%7C2013-03-12T19%3A25%3A23%2B00%3A00%7C09161a6011f2dc2e3443bc40b2d3f4b3d4f
```

Comment: org.apache.common.langs.StringUtils

Comment: What does url look like before going into the String.format call?

Comment: What does url and callnumber look like?

Comment: Added output to question. I bet that end string contains % is messing it up, thanks guys.

Comment: Is there a better solution to do this other then having two methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is "%3D" in the `url` string to be formatted due to URL escaping.  You will need to supply the result of `GetAuthTokenEncoded` as a parameter to `String.format` so it doesn't interpret "%3D" as a placeholder.

```
String url = StringUtils.join(new String[] { BASE_URL,
            "/location/inst/", part,
            "/coursesections/number%s.json?apiKey=", apiKey,
            "&token=%s");
String url2 = String.format(url, ("/" + callNumber), GetAuthTokenEncoded(authToken));
```

Answer (score 2):

`GetAuthTokenEncoded(authToken)` contains a whole load of `%` causing errors.  Why not just append the callNumber in the same way you are joining the rest of the String?

```
String url = StringUtils.join(new String[] { BASE_URL,
            "/location/inst/", part,
            "/coursesections/number/", number, ".json?apiKey=", apiKey,
            "&token=", GetAuthTokenEncoded(authToken) })
```

Comment: Yep Ill figure out another solution.